# Convert Geometry from Multipolygons to Polygons

Tags: tableau-api, shapefile

I have a worksheet in tableau which uses shapefiles of a state at district level. But when I bring it into the view, and hover over anything, all of it gets highlighted. I found out the Geometry is set to MULTIPOLYGONS instead of POLYGONS. How can I convert multipolygons to polygons so I can hover over each district and get their details in the tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapefiles are normally constructed with one Multipolygon per district (at least for districts that need more than one polygon to describe the area as many do). So when you select a single district, you get *all* the geometry associated with the district. This is intentional and the right behaviour for highlighting districts (or whatever unit you are working with).

What is probably happening for you is that you have displayed a map but haven't put the district identifier onto the Tableau "detail" shelf. In this case the *whole" map will highlight. This has nothing to do with Multipolygons. It is a deliberate choice in Tableau to allow for the possibility of maps containing multiple hierarchical areas.

In the UK, for example, you can get shapefiles with low level census areas called LSOAs. But the data will also contain how these fit together into higher-level areas (MSOAs, local authorities, parliamentary constituencies etc.). Using the low-level shapefile with the higher-area information is possible by dragging the names of the higher-level areas into the details shelf making them the unit of analysis for the map.

If you don't drag any area name into the detail shelf, Tableau will assume the *whole* map is the unit for aggregation and will highlight everything.

So fix the problem by dragging the unit names or identifiers for your districts to the shelf and everything will work.